# selecting unique records monthly basis

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one table, records like

```
id      date       branch
1001    01/01/2015  VBR
1002    02/05/2015  CBR
1001    03/01/2015  VBr
1005    05/05/2015  CBR
1005    12/12/2015  VBR
1006    05/05/2015  CBR
```

I need to select records monthly wise (date wise) but it should be unique, otherwise it should not be in any other month
eg: if I select month 5/2015 it should return 1006

Comment: How are you getting the input?

Comment: It is a log data so i need to know the unique records of the specific month.

Comment: what about your date format. mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?. What is the datatype of your date column either it is varchar or date. Actually I get two records 1005 and 1006 when we pass input as 5/2015

Comment: format is mm/dd/yyyy and date column is 'date' format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID FROM 
(
    SELECT 1001 AS ID,   '01/01/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'VBR' AS branch FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1002 AS ID,   '02/05/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'CBR' AS branch FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1001 AS ID,   '03/01/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'VBR' AS branch FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1005 AS ID,   '05/05/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'CBR' AS branch FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1005 AS ID,   '12/12/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'VBR' AS branch FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 1006 AS ID,   '05/05/2015' AS MY_DATE, 'CBR' AS branch FROM DUAL
)
where LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, MY_DATE,112),6) = '052015'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
```

Comment: can I use variable for the date since it is very large data

Comment: I assume yes, this is just a sample code, you can utilize your coding skills to use it according to your requirements

Comment: this code select monthly records but it is not filtering the previous date's data. the main issue of the code is that it should not show the previous data

Comment: what you are saying is not clear, code above will get you unique data for the desired year and month you supply, if the same ID is found in other dates it will not be selected, if you have other requirements and facing difficulties in tangling it, add more details to your question to elaborate your issue more

Comment: ' if the same ID is found in other dates it will not be selected' that I wanted actually. but where is this clause in the above code? that I confuse

Comment: this `where` statement is a **month** and **year** combination :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     id     INT,
     date1  DATE,
     branch VARCHAR(10)
  )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES      ('1001',
             '01/01/2015',
             'VBR'),
            ('1002',
             '02/05/2015',
             'CBR'),
            ('1001',
             '03/01/2015',
             'VBr'),
            ('1005',
             '05/05/2015',
             'CBR'),
            ('1005',
             '12/12/2015',
             'VBR'),
            ('1006',
             '05/05/2015',
             'CBR')
```

To return all records

```
SELECT *
FROM   @table
WHERE  Year(date1) = 2015
       AND Month(date1) = 5
```

To return the latest record

```
SELECT max(id) id
FROM   @table
WHERE  Year(date1) = 2015
       AND Month(date1) = 5 
group by date1
```